# How to insert a list of numbers after an existing list of numbers

Tags: sql

I have a column in a database where I store pin numbers for a survey.  Currently the list of numbers is 5100 - 6674.  I need to keep those pin numbers there for a current survey but I also have to add a new list of pin numbers to the same column.  I just want to make sure the query that I have created will insert the new list into the column without affecting the old list. There is also another column which gives the survey type.  I need to also add the new type to the new list so for example, currently I have the list of pins ranging from 5100 - 6674 with a Survey type of CLN.  The next list is a range of numbers from 8100 - 8855 with a survey type of TM. I do not want to mess anything up with the current survey that is currently running so I have one shot to get it right, otherwise there will be a big mess.  Here is the query I have come up with.

```
DECLARE @PIN INT
SET @PIN = 8100
WHILE (@PIN <= 8855)
BEGIN
    Insert into Survey (Pin) values (@PIN)
    Select @PIN = @PIN + 1
    from Survey
    where Pin > 6674
END

UPDATE Survey SET Type = 'TM'
WHERE Pin > 6674
```

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you set the `type` at the same time as the pin and fix the increment step:

```
DECLARE @PIN INT;
SET @PIN = 8100;
WHILE (@PIN <= 8855)
BEGIN
    Insert into Survey(Pin, Type)
        values (@PIN, @TYPE);

    set @PIN = @PIN + 1;
END;
```

You can also do this with a single statement, if you want to learn a bit more SQL:

```
with pins as (
      select 8100 as pin
      union all
      select pin + 1
      from pins
      where pin < 8855
  )
Insert into Survey(Pin, Type)
    select pin, 'TM'
    from pins;
option (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are inserting fewer numbers you can just select a range from the existing set and add a constant:

```
INSERT INTO Survey (PIN, Type)
SELECT Pin + 3000, 'TM'
FROM Survey
WHERE Pin BETWEEN 5100 and 5855
```

If you were inserting MORE values, you could use the same technique but in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding how you're inserting this data I don't really see anything wrong with the approach you're taking. Regardless if PIN is a primary key it will be distinct by default and not allow for you to insert duplicate records.

You may also consider adding a column to record the point in time in which you created the data in case you know at a specific day/time you messed something up.